# MySQL / ASP.NET Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, mysql, stored-procedures

Hopefully this is not a [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) question...

I'm working forward on migrating a project from storing data in XML Serialization to a MySQL  database. I'm using the example provided me from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379560/xml-serializiation-migration-to-mysql) answered yesterday.

Connecting using phpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench I've created a Stored Procedure called 'sprocOrderSelectSingleItem'. It seems to work well with MySQL for all I can tell. When I run the **SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE sprocOrderSelectSingleItem** it returns the following:

`CREATE DEFINER=username@% PROCEDURE sprocOrderSelectSingleItem(IN orderID INTEGER) 
BEGIN SELECT * FROM tblOrders WHERE ID=orderID; END`

My cooperative ASP.NET code goes something like this:

```
public static Order GetItem(int ID)
{
    Order objOrder = null;

    using (OdbcConnection objConnection = new OdbcConnection(Utils.ApplicationConfiguration.ConnectionString))
    {
        OdbcCommand objCommand = new OdbcCommand("sprocOrderSelectSingleItem", objConnection);
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderID", ID);
        objConnection.Open();

        using (OdbcDataReader objReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (objReader.Read())
            {
                objOrder = FillDataRecord(objReader);
            }

            objReader.Close();
        }

        objConnection.Close();
    }

    return objOrder;
}
```

When I view the page I get the following error message:

*ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.77]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sprocOrderSelectSingleItem' at line 1*

Really not catching on to what could be missing or going wrong. Are there any additional tests I should/could be running to confirm things are working on the MySQL side? Am I missing a step to pass the Stored Procedure call correctly in ASP.NET? The code breaks at the line of:

```
using (OdbcDataReader objReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader())
```

Replacing the line of

```
OdbcCommand objCommand = new OdbcCommand("sprocOrderSelectSingleItem", objConnection);
```

with this instead

```
OdbcCommand objCommand = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM tblOrders WHERE ID=" + ID + ";", objConnection);
```

and everything works as expected.

Thanks for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: A better title should have been ASP.NET / MySQL Stored Procedures. I understand the damage of dyslexia now. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can run an execute on sprocOrderSelectSingleItem in Mysql directly with the ID parameter.
It will show that your StoredProc run correctly.

Here is a sample code in C# that call a stored proc.

```
OdbcCommand salesCMD = new OdbcCommand("{ CALL SalesByCategory(?) }", nwindConn);
salesCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OdbcParameter myParm = salesCMD.Parameters.Add("@CategoryName", OdbcType.VarChar, 15);
myParm.Value = "Beverages";

OdbcDataReader myReader = salesCMD.ExecuteReader();
```

Look at the "Call" in the OdbcCommand and the "?" for the parameter that is later supplied with a value.

Comment: I now get this error message when using your method: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.77]Thread stack overrun:  4120 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 131072 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

Comment: The new error seems to be related to this link: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15629. Looks to be a server issue now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like below:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "{call LoadCustCliOrders(?,?,?,?)}";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("CUST_ID",OdbcType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("CLIENT_ID",OdbcType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("DATE_FROM",OdbcType.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("DATE_TO",OdbcType.Date);

...

    cmd.Parameters["CUST_ID"].Value = _CustId;
    cmd.Parameters["CLIENT_ID"].Value =  _ClientId;
    cmd.Parameters["DATE_FROM"].Value = _DateFrom;
    cmd.Parameters["DATE_TO"].Value = _DateTo;

    cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: I now get this error message when using your method: ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.77]Thread stack overrun: 4120 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 131072 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack

Comment: The new error seems to be related to this link: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15629. Looks to be a server issue now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please increase threadstack and try again. Make it 256K and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the same username or user with the same access privileges.
I think you need to add the word "CALL" before the stored proc.
It should be CALL sprocOrderSelectSingleItem and try.

Comment: I've verified the account and privileges. I was missing the CALL keyword though. That much is apparent now.