# Call MYSQL stored procedure through c#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a MYSQL stored procedure through c# but it keeps giving me an error saying that

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''55\'', 'UserEmail','Username@company-it.pk\''' at line 1 "

Sp takes three input parameters User_id, preferences_key and preferences_value. I have checked the sp by executing it through MYSQL it works properly but i want to excute it through c#. below is the code.

```
mySqlContext = new MySql_OtrsEntities();

var userid=mySqlContext.users.Where(x=>x.login==agent.login).Select(x=>x.id).FirstOrDefault();

MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("@User_id", agent.id);
param1.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
MySqlParameter param2 = new MySqlParameter("@preferences_key", "UserEmail");
param2.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
MySqlParameter param3 = new MySqlParameter("@preferences_value", agent.login);
param3.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.LongBlob;

mySqlContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("call InsertUserPreferences @User_id, @preferences_key,@preferences_value",
                                  param1, param2,param3);
```

Comment: What library are you using? This code is neither ADO.NET nor Entity Framework

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL / ASP.NET Stored Procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391573/mysql-asp-net-stored-procedures)

Comment: Well i am using this MySQL Connector/Net 6.9.5.0 which is a ADO.NET driver for MYSQL

Comment: I want to execute the SP directly through Entity framework.